# CGo Convert go string to *C.uchar

Tags: c, go, cgo

```
var originalMsg *C.uchar
C.ecall_pay_w(8, 10, &originalMsg, &signature)
originalMsgStr := fmt.Sprintf("%c", originalMsg)

//Todo convert originalMstStr to same value with originalMsg
```

i have to convert go str(originalMsgStr) to *C.uchar type which is same value with originalMsg.
How can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a C-string back from your call to `C.ecall_pay_w` and want to convert that C-string to a Go-string. You can do this by manually following the C-string until you reach the terminating `0`.

Assuming that:

- There is a terminating `0` at the end of the C-string
- The C-string is encoded as ASCII, so every byte represents an ASCII character (in the range  [0..127]). This means it is both ASCII and UTF-8 at the same time because UTF-8 is backward compatible to ASCII.

Then your solution could be this:

```
    func convertCStringToGoString(c *C.uchar) string {
        var buf []byte
        for *c != 0 {
            buf = append(buf, *c)
            c = (*C.uchar)(unsafe.Pointer(uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(c)) + 1))
        }
        return string(buf)
    }
```

Note that doing "unsafe" things like this in Go is cast-heavy. That was done on purpose by the Go authors. You need to convert to `unsafe.Pointer` before you can convert to `uintptr`. The `uintptr` can be added to (`+ 1`) while the `unsafe.Pointer` does not support that. These are the reasons for that much casting.

Comment: well i try to convert like that, and print value of cPointer. it is different from originalMessage.

Comment: What I want is to convert the 'originalMessage' to 'go string', then send it through grpc, and the other side converts the message received as string to the original original message and put it into the function

Comment: I am sorry, I read your question wrong. I updated it now to do what you asked.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know Go in much detail, but do not forget that in C the `*C.uchar` would be something like `unsigned char *` which is often used to reference a string (Null-terminated array of characters).

Here you use `fmt.Sprintf("%c", originalMsg)`, with `%c` which expects a single char, so apart from the language detail on how you would *cast* the resulting string to a `*C.uchar`, you most probably have lost *content* already.

> %c    the character represented by the corresponding Unicode code point

From https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#hdr-Printing